# Angular 6 Material - Hues and How to change the color of mat radio button

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

How can I change the color of the  using CSS?

Saw on another post that if I use the following code, it would change it, but I had no luck with it so far.

```
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color:rgb(255, 37, 37);
  }

.mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle {
    border-color: rgb(66, 134, 244);
}

.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
    background-color: rgb(66, 134, 244);
}
```

Also, how could I use the rest of the color hues?

```
<mat-radio-button color="accent">Hello, World</mat-radio-button>
```

Let's say that I want to use from the Accent color, the hue of 300 or A100, how would I go about to doing that?

I've tried using `accent-100` and `accent hue-100` but, it doesn't work

Answer (score 25, accepted):

add this css in your `style.css/style.scss`

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-hues-and-how-to-change-the-color-of-mat-radi?file=styles.css)**

**style.css/style.scss**

```
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle{
  border-color:rgb(66, 134, 244); 
}

.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle{
  color:rgb(66, 134, 244);
  background-color:rgb(66, 134, 244) ;
}

.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color:rgb(255, 37, 37,.26);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Comment: Is there only a "hack" solution? Yes custom styles on Material components which should do this job is hacking. If there is only a css solution, I recommend to use the color variable of Material instead of color code duplication.

Comment: Can you change the color of the effect when you click it? instead of pink?

Comment: @Danny22 yes, add !important under .mat-ripple-element

Comment: haha @Pony my comment has been there for 2 years, probably I have already fixed that. But thanks.

Comment: I put it here for others who might be struggling. and the 2 past years are redundant anyway thanks to covid ;)

Answer (score 18):

None of the above worked for me. But this one worked i.e put color="primary" on mat -radio button. ie

```
<mat-radio-button color="primary" value=1>Active</<mat-radio-button>.
```

See example below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-ethbcx

Comment: this is the best one.

Answer (score 6):

```
::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
  background-color: blue !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
  background-color: blue!important;   /*inner circle color change*/
}

::ng-deep.mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle {
 border-color:blue!important; /*outer ring color change*/
}
```

Comment: Be sure to ad :host before ::ng-deep. From docs: "..., be sure to include the :host selector before ::ng-deep. If the ::ng-deep combinator is used without the :host pseudo-class selector, the style can bleed into other components."

Comment: But for sure a great method to gather full control of material components styling with the help of global scoped rules through ::ng-deep. Quick and dirty but works!

Answer (score 3):

You can set custom color using following approach:

Put this code in your module declaration:

```
providers: [{
    provide: MAT_RADIO_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
    useValue: { color: 'accent' },
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was this, add this to your:

**style.css/style.scss**

```
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color:  rgb(22, 92, 125) !important;
}

.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
    background-color:  rgb(22, 92, 125) !important;
    z-index: 3;
}

.mat-radio-button .mat-radio-outer-circle {
    border-color:  rgb(22, 92, 125) !important; // Override material
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Little upgrade for the selected answer. worked for me.

```
$myMatRadioRippleColor: #0000FF;

::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent {
  &.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle {
    border-color: $myMatRadioRippleColor; 
  }

  .mat-radio-inner-circle {
    color: $myMatRadioRippleColor;
    background-color: $myMatRadioRippleColor ;
  }

  .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: $myMatRadioRippleColor !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me as of Angular 16 and Angular Material 15 was adding the following styles to my styles.scss:

```scss
.mat-mdc-radio-button.mat-mdc-radio-checked .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: #0028a0b0 !important;
}

.mat-mdc-radio-button.mat-mdc-radio-checked .mdc-radio__background::before {
    background-color: #0028a0b0 !important;
}

.mat-mdc-radio-button
    .mdc-radio
    .mdc-radio__native-control:enabled:checked
    + .mdc-radio__background
    .mdc-radio__outer-circle {
    border-color: #0028a0b0 !important;
}

.mat-mdc-radio-button .mdc-radio .mdc-radio__native-control:enabled + .mdc-radio__background .mdc-radio__inner-circle {
    border-color: #0028a0b0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on ng 13.1.2 and adding color attribute to my mat-radio-buttion worked for me

```
<mat-radio-button color="primary" style="..." class="..." value="..." (change)="...">
      RADIO LABEL
</mat-radio-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below css worked for me. I am using Angular 16 and Angular Material 16

```
    
// For outer circle

::ng-deep .mat-mdc-radio-button .mdc-radio .mdc-radio__native-control:enabled:checked+.mdc-radio__background .mdc-radio__outer-circle {
  border-color:#E31837 !important
}

//For inner circle

::ng-deep .mat-mdc-radio-button .mdc-radio .mdc-radio__native-control:enabled+.mdc-radio__background .mdc-radio__inner-circle {
  border-color: #E31837 !important
}
```