# How to change the color of mat-radio-outer-circle (angular material)

Tags: angular-material2

I would like to change the radio button color in angular material the default value is 'accent' and I would like to set this value #ff9800, I found this solution in SO, [Angular 6 Material - Hues and How to change the color of mat radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52552284/angular-6-material-hues-and-how-to-change-the-color-of-mat-radio-button) , but the .mat-radio-outer-circle its value remained in accent ,my question is how can i change its value (#ff9800) when the radio button is checked.Here is my css and html code.

```
/* border-color:rgb(66, 134, 244); */ 
::ng-deep.mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle { 
    color:#ff9800; 
    border-color: #ff9800;
}

::ng-deep.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle{
    color:#ff9800;
    background-color:#ff9800;
  }

::ng-deep.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
      background-color:#ff9800;
}
```

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" class="actions" [(ngModel)]="action"
                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
         <mat-radio-button value="Compile" checked ="true" color="accent">Compile</mat-radio-button>
         <mat-radio-button value="Check Syntax" color="accent">Check Syntax</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what is not working for you, please provide a *minimal reproducible example* (stackblitz).

Comment: Can you remove ```ng-deep``` and try it out?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `!important` rule after the value of the `border-color` and `background-color` like the following code:

```
::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: #ff9800 !important;
}

//before checked:

::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-outer-circle {
    border-color: green !important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
    background-color: green !important;
}

//after checked:

::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked
    .mat-radio-outer-circle {
    border-color: #ff9800 !important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked
    .mat-radio-inner-circle {
    background-color: #ff9800 !important;
}
```